# Redirect to template from controller and pass data

Tags: plugin-development, redirect, variable, modules

I am building a custom login process which follow these steps:

1. Request user email (submits to custom controller)
2. Check if user has an account
3. If they have an account, show a form requesting their password. Or if they don't have an account then send them to the registration form.

The forms exist as front end templates.

I can accomplish all these steps but when the user is redirected I need to make the email address that they entered available to the template.

My custom controller calls a service to check if the user exists which is all fine.
And I can redirect the user to the appropriate URL. But I can't figure out how to retain the email address they entered.

Currently I've just done it by appending the email as a query string but this is undesirable for a couple of reasons.

The controller currently looks like this although I feel this is totally the wrong way to be doing things.

```
public function actionEmailCheck() {
        $this->requirePostRequest();

        $email = Craft::$app->request->post('loginName');

        $result = MyModule::$instance->order->checkEmail($email);

        if($result) {
            $redirect = '/login/password?email='.$email;
        } else {
            $redirect = '/register?email='.$email;
        }

        $this->redirect($redirect);
    }
```

I feel like I should be able to set some template variables and load the appropriate template but that doesn't seem to work.

I also tried this

```
if($result) {
            $this->renderTemplate('/login/password', array('email'=>$email));
        } else {
            $this->renderTemplate('/register', array('email'=>$email));
        }
```

But while the template was displayed, I couldn't access the value for 'email'.

So how *should* I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by saving the email address to a custom session variable like this in your controller:

```
Craft::$app->getSession()->set('email', $email);
```

This should then be available in your template using:

```
{{ set email = craft.app.session.get('email') }}
```

Comment: I did try that but for some reason it wasn't working. I'll give it another go.

Comment: Well it worked that time with a minor change to `Craft::$app->getSession()->set('email',$email)`. Would still like to know if there's a way to do it without setting the session variable.

Comment: The only way to do it would be either to set a session variable or to pass GET variables to the redirect destination